# Как задать IP адреса и прокси компьютерам в сети?

Tags: python, c++, сеть, proxy, ethernet

Задача такая - сотня компов в кабинете. Каждому нужно присвоить айпишник, каждому надо задать прокси. Прокси одинаковые, айпишники отличаются одним числом.

Как обратиться к системе из-под яп? Я немного знаю питон и могу на нём из json-а составлять адреса. Чутка знаю плюсы - знаю как с ними можно автоматизировать.
Одно не понимаю - я не знаю как этими языками написать приложение, чтобы оно само меняла адреса компов и прокси - не знаю как к системе обратиться. Гугл выдаёт очевидное - как писать сервер на плюсах. А мне надо просто чтобы прога задавала параметры езернет адаптера и прокси.

Comment: Гугл подсказывает, что это можно делать через [`netsh`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/bb490939(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: а всего то нужно настроить dhcp (на "сервере"/роутере) и готово. По dhcp можно будет выдать все настройки сети, менять почти на лету. Также адреса можно привязать к мак адресам и вопрос будет решен.

Comment: Надо вопрошающего отослать к rfc 6148 по dhcp, раз он сам хочет всё сделать на яп. Может это его займёт на какое-то время (и мы долго не увидим его вопросов:)

Comment: Почему не дхцп - мне просто низя в дхцп. мне дают адреса - иди, вручную вписывай, и прокси туда, пожалуйста, тоже вручную впиши... Работа муторная, и регулярная.
В принципе мне подсказали про netsh, и я нашёл как можно сделать в тупую батником на флешке. Если кому-то будет полезно - есть вот такая статья на сайте. Разбирайте на запчасти.
https://ravensblade.ru/kb/1025/

Comment: А можно вот про этот момент поподробнее: "И настраивать приходится в условии отсутствии сети". Тут просто непонятно: вы же прописываете адреса, и тогда компьютер "обретает сеть". А ДО ЭТОГО он что, не присоединен к сети?

Comment: при ненастроенной сети - сети нет

Answer (score 2):

Вам KoVadim даёт очень правильный ответ. Так как вы решаете задачу, которую человечество решает уже лет 25, стОит к нему прислушаться.

DHCP специально предназначен для решения этой задачи. Более того, DHCP под Windows даже имеет довольно приятный графический интерфейс.

Если же пойти своим путём и начать решать задачу, разместив на каждом компе свою программу, которя будет его настраивать - вам придется написать распределенную систему, которая к тому же должна работать в условиях отсутствия сети: ведь в тот момент, когда Вы меняете компьютеру сетевые настройки - связь с сетью пропадает. Плюс, надо будет избегать конфликтов назначения двух одинковых IP разным компам. В общем, не простая задача.

Comment: Мне в дхцп нельзя - серверники не разрешают. Говорят "на адреса, иди вписывай в кампуктеры вручную". А кампуктеров ну очень много. И настраивать приходится в условии отсутствии сети. И вот весь пакет который вы перечислили.

Comment: тогда писать "свой dhcp" или почему "серверники" не занимаются этим? (хотя да, это не их задача, но тогда почему они указывают? или просто получили доступ к роутеру?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема удаленной настройки сети в том что на компьютере нет сети. Для автоматизации обычно используется dhcp. Но иногда админ сети не хочет ставить роутер, а раздает интернет компьютером с двумя сетевыми картами. Во времена моего студенцества такое видел. В основном из-за бюрократии и желании админа оставаться главным такое происходит.

Вариант простой - притащить роутер с опенврт или микротик и настроить раздачу прокси в параметрах dhcp.

Вариант посложнее - запустить на одном из подконтрольных компьютеров dhcp сервер с опциями настройки прокси. В минусах - не будет настроенна сеть если комп выключат, сложно найти дхчп сервер для виндовс.

Вариант со скриптом на флешке имеет только один минус - надо вставлять эту флешку.

### Вариант тоже сложный, но "программисткий":

Современные ос имеют автонастройку ip для локальной сети (169 адреса) и начинает работать мультикаст. Хотя можно и на бродкасте, если сеть не большая.

На каждый компьютер нужно установить демона (на питоне можно), который будет подключаться к мультикаст группе и анонсировать всем настройки и версию настроек, а также принимать, применять и сохранять  их для раздачи. На одном компе эти настроки правишь для всех и оно всем разлетелось.